# Error in External data source sync

Tags: lightning-connect

I am implementing the external data source feature in the salesforce .After creating external data source i tried sync but it throws an error **The server URL is invalid. Enter the server root URL of the external data source. Make sure that you escape any special characters in the URL.** Any idea about how to escape server url?.I have implemented two integration in this but i dint get any error like this.
 **https://xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxx/xx/xx/xx/x_xx_xx_xx_xx/xx_xx** this is what my server url looks like. i have hypen in the root **https://xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxx.com**

Comment: Do you get a valid OData page if you get the server root in a browser, like this: http://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc/ ?

Comment: Ya this is an  valid URL i tried in my browser.Its working fine .May be the hyphen in root is causing problem.

Comment: Hyphen shouldn't cause a problem. I think you have two choices: open a support ticket, or [wait for Winter '15](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/) and see if it works.